# Is it possbile to create a aws cron expression that will schedule the aws batch job to run on 1st, 2nd, and 3rd tuesday of every month?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-batch

I tried this cron expression on aws cron(00 11 ? * 3#1-3 *) but it's not working.

Are there any work arounds on this?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any work arounds on this?

Yes, creating three rules seems as the only option:

```
Rule 1: 0 11 ? * 3#1 *
Rule 2: 0 11 ? * 3#2 *
Rule 3: 0 11 ? * 3#3 *
```

Comment: is it possible to add three cron expression in one single batch job?

Comment: @HimanshuMishra Yes, each CW rule can trigger the same target, which in your case would be a batch job.